# htaccess allow multiple hosts

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using the following code and it doesn't work:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^arc14.pip.aber.ac.uk [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^jas31.pip.aber.ac.uk
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/soon\.php$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /soon.php [R=302,L]
```

but this does:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^arc14.pip.aber.ac.uk
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/soon\.php$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /soon.php [R=302,L]
```

I want to allow two, how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Continue to add more `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST}` lines

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^arc14.pip.aber.ac.uk
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^someplace.somewhere.com
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^whatever.anything.edu
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^idk.what.else
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/soon\.php$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /soon.php [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create .htaccess file and code the following lines.

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from <Give YOUR IP>,<Give YOUR IP>,<Give YOUR IP> and so on...
```

Comment: He is trying to do a maintainance page style htaccess. (Im def assuming here) He isn't going to want to present a 403 to everyone EXCEPT who is allowed. Its a much better technique to continue to allow them to a different page in the meantime.(And yes... You COULD change the 403 page to be whatever the contents of soon.php is, but then you would have to change it back when the site is open, and change it out again anytime you want to temp close it, ect)